# confluent JDBC-Sink Examples.table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent and kafka to sink the data from a Kafka topic to a Mysql table. My configs are

```
name=jdbc-sink 
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=foobar
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo1
connection.user=user
connection.password=pass
auto.create=true
```

i am using command

```
./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-quickstart-mysql.properties
```

so when foobar table is not present in demo1 database it gives error that table demo1.foobar does not exists.
So when i create foobar table in demo1 by myself then its giving error.

```
WARN Write of 2 records failed, remainingRetries=10 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:77)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'examples.foobar' doesn't exist
```

Is there any issue with my configurations?

Comment: What is `demo1`, `examples.foobar` and `foobar`? I assume that `demo1` is the database schema and `foobar` is a table. How about `examples.foobar` ?

Comment: demo1 and examples are both databases in mysql. As i had mentioned in my JDBC url still its connecting with examples database. Even i had not connected with that in my complete script

Comment: Are you running MySQL on the same machine as Kafka Connect? Are you sure it should be `localhost:3306`?